# cmd.exe : both capture a folder path and parse the folder name

Tags: for-loop, parsing, cmd, directory

In a `cmd.exe` batch file.

I have a directory `C:\Program Files\Java` containing the following directories.

```
\jdk-11.0.14
\jdk-17.0.2
\jdk1.8_321
```

I can easily parse these names using the `for /f` construct.

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2,3,4 delims=-._" %%G in (`dir /b /a:d  %ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk*"`) do (
@ echo Version = %%G %%H %%I
)
```

Giving...

```
Version = 11 0 14
Version = 17 0 2
Version = 8 0 321
```

And, I can get the paths with...

```
@ for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (`dir /b /a:d "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk*"`) do (
@ echo Path = %%G
)
```

```
Path = jdk-11.0.14
Path = jdk-17.0.2
Path = jdk1.8.0_321
```

What I want is the path and the version information for that path together.

Specifically, I need to perform an action on the path; if the version matches some condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that seems to work.

```
for /D %%G in ("%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk*") do (
  echo Path = %%G
  for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=-._" %%H in ("%%~nxG") do (
    echo Version = %%H %%I %%J
  )
)
```

Is there a better way?